# Make Rails Validation Helpers uniqueness multiple with a group of columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How i can validate four attributes at once using method uniqueness or if I have how?

I am use MySQL:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    validates :manufacturer,:model, :color,:carrier_plan_type, :quantity, :price, presence: true
    validates :quantity, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :manufacturer, confirmation: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :model, format: {with: /\w+\s\w{2}\s\d{2,3}GB/i }
    validates :color, format: {with: /[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+/i}
    validates :carrier_plan_type, format: {with: /p(re|os)/}
end
```

This is my model Product, i would like to 4 columns (manufacturer, model, color and carrier_plan_type) with method_uniqueness. So that it is only valid to insert an instance in my database if you do not have these 4 columns repeated.

I found in Rails Guide that:

> See the MySQL manual for more details about multiple column indexes or the PostgreSQL manual for examples of unique constraints that refer to a group of columns.

But i didn't understand how i can to group the columns.

To add, It is a good practice to do the validations as I did up there, if you have another opinion I am open to an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :carrier_plan_type, scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color]
```

or

```
validates :carrier_plan_type, uniqueness: { scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color] }
```

either should give you what you want.

In reply to the comment below try:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :carrier_plan_type,
    scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color, :price], if: -> { quantity == 0 }
```

or even

```
validates_uniqueness_of :carrier_plan_type,
    scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color, :price], if: :quantity_zero

private

  def quantity_zero
    quantity == 0
  end
```

Comment: Everything was OK with ` validates_uniqueness_of :carrier_plan_type, scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color]`   but i tried to increment one condition :if with the attribute :quantity , so that the only instance committed is the one with quantity 0. ` validates_uniqueness_of :carrier_plan_type, scope: [:manufacturer, :model, :color, :price], if: -> {:quantity == 0} ` . Can you help me?